# How to analyse the graph result of affinity propagation clustering in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I've installed **R**'s affinity propagation clustering package and read the [decomentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/apcluster/versions/1.4.5/topics/apcluster). The basic script to cluster the iris data is:

```
data(iris)
apIris1 <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), iris)
apIris1
```

With this code, six clusters are formed. Moreover, the result can be seen graphically with following code:

```
plot(apIris1, iris)
```

The produced graph is as follows:

[image]

The available information regarding this plot is: *each color corresponds to one cluster. The exemplar of each cluster is marked by a
box and all cluster members are connected to their exemplars with lines.* **Are there any other ways to analyze this plot?** For example: What is the difference between each large box (that contains colorful data) containing six clusters?What is the relation between them? When I try to plot only the data with `plot(iris)` , the same plot is produced without color (black dots) and without clustering. How can I analyze the data plot?

Moreover, the heatmap can be produced with `heatmap(apIris1)` which is as follows:

[image]

As seen in the plot above, the different colors on the top and left side depicts the total number of clusters. **How can I analyze this plot in detail**?

Any help, please!

Sorry for the lengthy post!

**Update:**

[image]

Here, The large boxes connected by **1**,**3**, and **4** (excluding the boxes with feature name) have similar kind of data distribution, respectively. However, boxes connected by **2** has mirrored distribution. What does this different data distribution really say? If there were just one large box plot, it would be easy to visualize. However, the boxes with different data distribution/pattern have confused me. Can we relate each row or column with their respective feature name?

Comment: the questions you have asked are broad in scope. Try to narrow down the scope. Let me ask you, "Why do you need affinity propagation method for your problem at hand?"

Comment: Affinity propagation clustering helps to reduce computational complexity in my work. I want to analyze it in more detail before using it.

Comment: if computational complexity reduction is the criteria, then why not try Principal Component Analysis (PCA), a dimensionality reduction technique?

Comment: @Ashish I've my own requirements to use APC in my work. Could you help to elaborate the graph plot, please?

Comment: like I previously said the questions you have asked are too broad in context. By asking you all these questions I was trying to narrow down the focus. But it seems you have your own reasons. Unless, the questions asked are focused, I'm sorry there is nothing much I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four dimensional data.

Each of the "large boxes" in the plot correspond to a 2 dimensional view of your data, based on selecting just 2 features as x and y.

The heatmap plot is more appropriate for *hierarchical* clustering. You can see that clusters are consistent (white), but also some different clusters are mostly white (intersection of blue and cyan), so they are not too well separated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the four-dimensional data mean four features? I'm still confused with the information on the "large boxes'. Please see the update on the question.

Comment: Yes, four features. They are labeled in the diagonal boxes. And yes, in this data set, the sepal feature are somewhat similar and the petal features are also somewhat similar... And if you swap the x and y axes, then yes, you get a mirrored result...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the theory behind `apcluster`, and what `negDistMat()` does, but I'd call

`apIris1 <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=6), iris[,1:4])`

then you'll get *three* clusters for some reason (as you should, because there are 3 Species), then compare cluster assignments to actual labels  with

```
library(purrr)
nclust       <- map_dbl(apIris1@clusters, length) %>%  length()
iris$cluster <- map_dbl(apIris1@clusters, length) %>%  rep(1:nclust, .)

#visually compare two pairplots by switching back and forth in RStudio
pairs(iris[,1:4], col=factor(iris$cluster))
pairs(iris[,1:4], col=factor(iris$Species))
```